# TensorFlow: How to embed float sequences to fixed size vectors?

Tags: tensorflow, embedding, autoencoder

I am looking methods to embed variable length sequences with float values to  fixed size vectors.  The input formats as following:

`[f1,f2,f3,f4]->[f1,f2,f3,f4]->[f1,f2,f3,f4]-> ... -> [f1,f2,f3,f4]
[f1,f2,f3,f4]->[f1,f2,f3,f4]->[f1,f2,f3,f4]->[f1,f2,f3,f4]-> ... -> [f1,f2,f3,f4]
...
[f1,f2,f3,f4]-> ... -> ->[f1,f2,f3,f4]`

Each line is a variable length sequnece, with max length 60. Each unit in one sequece is a tuple of 4 float values. I have already paded zeros to fill all sequences to the same length.

The following architecture seems solve my problem if I use the output as the same as input, I need the **thought vector** in the center as the embedding for the sequences.
[image]

In tensorflow, I have found tow candidate methods [tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.basic_rnn_seq2seq](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/basic_rnn_seq2seq) and [tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_seq2seq).

However, these tow methos seems to be used to solve NLP problem, and the input must be discrete value for words.

So, is there another functions to solve my problems?

Comment: Do you mean you need a [recurrent layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Recurrent_Neural_Networks), such as [LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell) or [GRU](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/GRUCell)? That's what is generally used to produce a vector that depends on a variable number of fixed-size inputs (in fact your picture seems to feature LSTM units).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, using the following architecture,

[image],

The LSTMs layer below encode the series x1,x2,...,xn. The last output, the green one, is duplicated to the same count as the input for the decoding LSTM layers above. The tensorflow code is as following

```
series_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, conf.max_series, conf.series_feature_num])
print("Encode input Shape", series_input.get_shape())

# encoding layer
encode_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
  [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(conf.rnn_hidden_num, reuse=False) for _ in range(conf.rnn_layer_num)]
)
encode_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(encode_cell, series_input, dtype=tf.float32, scope='encode')
print("Encode output Shape", encode_output.get_shape())

# last output
encode_output = tf.transpose(encode_output, [1, 0, 2])
last = tf.gather(encode_output, int(encode_output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

# duplite the last output of the encoding layer
decoder_input = tf.stack([last for _ in range(conf.max_series)], axis=1)
print("Decoder input shape", decoder_input.get_shape())

# decoding layer
decode_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
  [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(conf.series_feature_num, reuse=False) for _ in range(conf.rnn_layer_num)]
)
decode_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(decode_cell, decoder_input, dtype=tf.float32, scope='decode')
print("Decode output", decode_output.get_shape())

# Loss Function
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=series_input, predictions=decode_output)
print("Loss", loss)
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is only an RNN, not the seq2seq model, since seq2seq goes with an additional decoder which is unecessary in your case.

An example code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

input_size = 4
max_length = 60
hidden_size=64
output_size = 4

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, max_length, input_size], name='x')
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None], name='seqlen')

lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=x, sequence_length=seqlen, dtype=tf.float32)


encoded_states = states[-1]

W = tf.get_variable(
        name='W',
        shape=[hidden_size, output_size],
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
b = tf.get_variable(
        name='b',
        shape=[output_size],
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

z = tf.matmul(encoded_states, W) + b
results = tf.sigmoid(z)

###########################
## cost computing and training components goes here
# e.g. 
# targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_size], name='targets')
# cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets, logits=z))
# optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(cost)
###############################

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()



batch_size = 4
data_in = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length, input_size), dtype='float32')
data_in[0, :4, :] = np.random.rand(4, input_size)
data_in[1, :6, :] = np.random.rand(6, input_size)
data_in[2, :20, :] = np.random.rand(20, input_size)
data_in[3, :, :] = np.random.rand(60, input_size)
data_len = np.asarray([4, 6, 20, 60], dtype='int64')



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    #########################
    # training process goes here
    #########################
    res = sess.run(results, 
            feed_dict={
                x: data_in, 
                seqlen: data_len})

print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you all the same

Answer (score 1):

To encode sequence to a fixed length vector you typically use recurrent neural networks (RNNs) or convolutional neural networks (CNNs).

If you use a recurrent neural network you can use the output at the last time step (last element in your sequence). This corresponds to the thought vector in your question. Have a look at [tf.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn). `dynamic_rnn` requires you to specify to type of RNN cell you want to use. `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell` and `tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell` are most common.

If you want to use CNNs you need to use 1 dimensional convolutions. To build CNNs you need [tf.layers.conv1d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv1d) and [tf.layers.max_pooling1d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/max_pooling1d)

Comment: I want to use neural network to embed the variable length sequences to fixed length vectors. I have already paded the sequences to the same max length

Comment: Thank you all the same